# How does 8086 read 16 bits of data from two 8 bit eproms?

Tags: x86-16

I have an 8086 in min mode. I have 2 eproms which have 16 address lines and 8 data lines. On reset the address is set to FFFF0
I have connected the two eproms to the lower 16 address lines via two 74ls373 latch and one eprom to do to d7 and other to d8 to d15
Both eproms have a short bit of code as a test with a mov to ax 45 and an add to ax 6 and a move to address 6000 ax instruction which all fit in the FFF0 to FFFA addresses in the eproms. Idea is cpu reads 16 bits with 8 from one eprom and 8 from other eprom. Address line set on eprom is FFF0 but do I just connect a0 address on 2nd eprom to high so it gives odd address and only connect a15 to a1 to  its address lines as if I connect a0 to a15 to both eproms then both are getting address FFF0 ? The next address the cpu selects is FFF2 so it increments in 2. Or do I have both eproms with the exact same address FFF0 but the data instruction is shifted in 2nd eprom

I connected the a0 to a15 address lines from the latches to both but it didn’t seem to read the code in the eproms